# Как заавтовайрить cпринговый @Component в HttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Всем привет. У меня возникла задача - в `HttpSessionListener` инкрементить и декрементить счетчик активных сессий. Счетчик есть спринговым `@Component`. Слушатель прописан в `web.xml`. `@Autowired` не работает, ссылка остается `null`. Возможно, кто-то знает правильный способ решения такой задачи?

Comment: Нужен именно `HttpSessionListener` или подойдут другие способы реагировать на событие создания и удаления сессии?

Comment: Подойдут и другие

Answer (score 3):

Если не обязателен именно `HttpSessionListener`, а нужно просто реагировать на события создания и удаления сессий, то стоит воспользоваться механизмом событий Spring. Для публикации событий можно взять готовый компонент Spring Security:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
       org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

И опубликовать свой компонент-слушатель:

```
@Component
public class SessionListener {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionCreated(HttpSessionCreatedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Но можно добиться внедрения зависимостей и в обычный `HttpSessionListener`, только придётся изменить способ его регистрации:

```
@Component
public class SomeHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener, ApplicationContextAware {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext()
                                                        .addListener(this);
        } else {
            // Можно просто ничего не делать, а можно выбросить исключение
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be inside a web application context");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```